# pandas: add value based on another column's value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which looks like this:

```
df
                    dim_pptx  qp_pptx  diff
Absolute Radio          7.39     7.53  0.14
BBC Asian Network       0.13     0.13  0.00
BBC Radio 1            14.41    14.55  0.14
BBC Radio 1Xtra         0.57     0.58  0.01
BBC Radio 2            23.36    23.39  0.03
```

I want to add a new column which contains values based on df['diff']

Expected output:

```
df
                    dim_pptx  qp_pptx  diff  sig
Absolute Radio          7.39     7.53  0.14   **
BBC Asian Network       0.13     0.13  0.00    - 
BBC Radio 1            14.41    14.55  0.14   **
BBC Radio 1Xtra         0.57     0.58  0.01    -
BBC Radio 2            23.36    23.39  0.03    *
```

so the condition would be:

```
if value > 0.1:
    value = '**'
elif value > 0.02:
    value = '*'
else:
    value = '-'
```

my attempt:

```
comp_df['sig'] = comp_df.apply(lambda x : '*' if comp_df['diff'] > 0.01 else '', axis=0)
```

error:

```
 ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index dim_pptx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) if you use `axis=0` it applies the condition through columns, to use `apply` to go through each row, you need `axis=1`.

But given that, you can use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) instead of [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the `'diff'` series. Example -

```
comp_df['sig'] = comp_df['diff'].apply(lambda x: '**' if x > 0.1 else '*' if x > 0.02 else '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set all the values that meet your criteria rather than looping over the df by calling `apply` so the following should work and as it's vectorised will scale better for larger datasets:

```
df.loc[df['diff'] > 0.1,'sig'] = '**'
df.loc[(df['diff'] > 0.02) & (df['diff'] <= 0.1), 'sig'] = '*'
df.loc[df['diff'] <= 0.02, 'sig'] = '-'
```

this will set all rows that meet the criteria, the problem using `apply` is that it's just syntactic sugar for a `for` loop and where possible this should be avoided where a vectorised solution exists.